# Regular expression to get anything between two specified characters

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expressions, I am trying to get all strings between '#' and space or any white space.

I have a string like this:

```
gray 47 #787878 120 120 120 7895160  
gray 46 #757575 117 117 117 7697781
gray 45 #737373 115 115 115 7566195
gray 44 #707070 112 112 112 7368816
gray 43 #6E6E6E 110 110 110 7237230
gray 42 #6B6B6B 107 107 107 7039851
```

and I would like to get just the RGB codes from it:

```
787878
757575
737373
707070
6E6E6E
6B6B6B
```

I am trying regex like this:

```
\#\w+\s
```

I am testing this on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and it says: no matches.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to escape the octothorpe; it's just a literal '#' character. Also, if you don't want to keep the space, you should make it non-capturing. Something like the following:

```
/(?:#)(\w+)(?:\s)/g
```

In fact, you should be able to just specify 6-digit alphanumerics to make it even more specific and then it won't look for underscores, for example:

```
/(?:#)([\da-zA-Z]{6})/g
```

**EDIT:**

Added parentheses to make it capture the data you care about.

**EDIT 2:**

> Please could you elaborate on what exactly means 'You shouldn't need
>   to escape the octothorpe' and 'make it non-capturing' in separate
>   regex examples.

Certain characters are given special meaning by regex engines. Here are a few examples:

```
$
^
.
+
```

If you wanted to match any of these characters literally, using regex, you would have 'escape' these characters. For example, if you had some text like this: "?$^EATING??" and you wanted to match "EATING??", you would need to write a regex like this: `EATING\?\?` because "?" is special.

If you put a `\` in front of a special character, this is called "escaping" it so that regex engine will treat it as a literal character.

The octothorpe character (this thing: **#**) is *not* a special character, so you do not need to escape it. It's treated literally, just like the following characters: `8 o`.

In addition, you can look for stuff using regexes, but not "capture" that stuff. It's a way of saying the following:

"I want to find an 'a', followed by a 'b', followed by a 'c', but I want to keep the 'a' and the 'b' and throw away the 'c'."

Non-capture groups are how you typically accomplish this.

Comment: the result includes # sign, which I do not want, but please could you elaborate on what exactly means 'You shouldn't need to escape the octothorpe' and 'make it non-capturing' in separate regex examples, bacause I don't understand your regex at all

Comment: also, why do you have /# instead of \# ? Please explain

Comment: the first and last '/' are related to the regex engine on that page you linked: that's how Javascript denotes a regex pattern. The *actual* pattern is between those.

Comment: /(?:#)(\w+)(?:\s)/g Hi can we not have to strict check with $ for this regex..? like  **/(?:#)(\w+)(?:\s)$/g** coz i want to knw about this thing

Comment: The dollar sign means "line ending" and line *does not* end at that final space, so that will fail.

Comment: thank you very much for your input, excellent explanation, I am going to read through your answer and test the regex tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You should use positive lookbehind and positive lookahead:

```
/(?<=#)\w+(?=\s)/g
```

This will only match all strings between '#' and space or any white space.

**Output**

```
787878
757575
737373
707070
6E6E6E
6B6B6B
```

---

> **Positive lookbehind**
>
> Positive lookbehind with `?<=` checks that its subpattern could match immediately to the left of the current position in the text string.

The regexp `(?<=#)\w+\s` matches `787878` , but only if it is preceded by `#`.

> **Positive lookahead**
>
> Positive lookahead with `?=` peeks ahead to ensure that its subpattern could match.

The regexp `#\w+(?=\s)` matches `#787878`, but only if it is followed by `/s`(any white space character).

So you should use regexp `/(?<=#)\w+(?=\s)/g` or just `/(?<=#)\w+/g` which will match `787878`, if it is followed by `/s` and preceded by `#`.

Comment: what do you mean by lookbehind and lookahead?

Comment: also, what does '?<='  and '?=' mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution

```
\#\w+\s
```

matches all lines for me so I suspect you're doing something wrong on the site. If you cut and paste be sure to use "paste as plain text". Try building the regex up bit by bit and ensure it matches as expected each time.
eg

```
#
```

then

```
#\w
```

This should do what you want

```
#(\w+\s)
```